# Windows : run script as other user, leave command line open for navigation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, remote-access, drive

I want to run a script as another user, which opens a command line prompt, connects a remote drive (to which I only have access as this other user) using `net use`, goes to said drive, and then into a path with spaces, and then leaves the command line open on this drive for the actual human user (me) to navigate and do stuff.

How to achieve this ?

Acceptable would be to open an instance of `explorer.exe` as this other user with this drive connected, instead of an instance of `cmd.exe`.

It seems `runas` opens a different line of execution which then closes. So the session where the drive is connected is short-lived.

The script could also open a cmd.exe as this user and pass commands to it via piping. But I also do not know how to specify which cmd.exe instance I mean, and Windows guesses wrong.

One solution which requires two files :

1- The script to connect the remote drive called `connect_drive.bat` :

```
net use s: /d /y
net use s: \\<server>\<path>
s:
cd <path with spaces>
```

2- The script to open a command prompt as the correct user and start by connecting the drive, then leaving the command prompt open, called `open_cmd_and_connect_drive.bat` :

```
runas /user:<domain>\<username> "start connect_drive.bat"
```

(note : I use options `/savecred` and `/env` to `runas locally.)`

Can I do better ?

Comment: `runas /user:domain\user "cmd /k c:\app\connect_drive.bat"`

Comment: Feels like I tried this already, but okay, this is the right answer. Thank you. Here, have an upvote ! \o/